# JOIN rows from 3 tables WHERE tableA.column1 = tableB.column1 = tableC.column1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables, structured like so:

```
TABLE A:
ID | PCID | ACTIVE | COHORT | WEEKLY_MEETING_TIME | FYE_ID | RC | AGREEMENT_SIGNED | RELEASE_SIGNED | NOTES | FACULTY_ADVISOR 

TABLE B:
ID | QUARTER | OFFICE | WRITING_CENTER | etc.. | etc.. | etc.. |

TABLE C:
ID | QUARTER | WEEK | EMAIL | etc.. | etc.. | etc.. |
```

The common element between all 3 tables is the `ID` field.

I need to `SELECT` from all 3 tables, and have each row represent one `ID` and all the values associated with that ID.

So, for example, each output row should look like a combination of the three tables:

```
RESULTS:
ID | PCID | ACTIVE | COHORT | WEEKLY_MEETING_TIME | FYE_ID | RC | AGREEMENT_SIGNED | RELEASE_SIGNED | NOTES | FACULTY_ADVISOR | QUARTER | OFFICE | WRITING_CENTER | etc.. | etc.. | etc.. | WEEK | EMAIL | etc.. | etc.. | etc.. |
```

I have no idea how to structure a query like this. I suspect it involves using `JOIN`s but my attempts have proved futile.

**how can I combine the data from 3 tables, based on shared ID field?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA
INNER JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEA.ID = TABLEB.ID
INNER JOIN TABLEC ON TABLEA.ID = TABLEC.ID
```

If you don't need all the values substitute the "*" with the names of the fields you need (ex. TABLEA.ID, TABLEB.QUARTER, TABLEC.WEEK...)

Comment: What if I want nearly all the values, and just want to specify a couple to NOT include? I want all the data but one or two columns from certain tables.

Comment: also -- if I want to change the ordering of the columns (ie I'd like to have a "first_name" column directly after the ID column), how would I do that?

Comment: You may use the select TABLE.* for the table where you need all the fields and you need to specify field by field for the tables where you need only some fields.
For the order of the fields after the SELECT statement you may specify all the column you need and the query output will respect the order you've inserted in the query.

Comment: If the anwer is ok for you may you please set as answered? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NATURAL JOIN works in MySQL:

select * from A natural join B natural join C

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT / WHAT YOU NEED TO SELECT - NOT * !!!/
FROM TABLEA
INNER JOIN TABLEB USING (ID)
INNER JOIN TABLEC  USING (ID)
```